# Momentum conservation in correlation functions

Tags: superconductivity, many-body, correlation-functions, quantum-tunneling

In Mahan "Many particle physics" the following Hamiltonian is considered in studying electron tunnelling through a junction
\begin{equation}
H_t = \sum_{kp} T_{kp} c^\dagger_k c_p + h.c.
\end{equation}
Here $c_k$ are the creation/annihilation operators on one side of the junction and $c_p$ on the other side of the junction.

The following correlator is then introduced at p.564 in studying single-electron tunnelling
\begin{equation}
U(i\omega) = -\sum_{kp\sigma} \sum_{k'p'\sigma'} T_{kp} T^*_{k'p'} \int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau} \langle \mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{k\sigma}(\tau)c_{p\sigma}(\tau) c^\dagger_{p'\sigma'}(0) c_{k'\sigma'}(0)] \rangle
\end{equation}

Mahan then states that only the $k=k', p=p', \sigma=\sigma'$ terms enter so that
\begin{equation}
U(i\omega) = -\sum_{kp\sigma} |T_{kp}|^2  \int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau} \langle \mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{k\sigma}(\tau)c_{p\sigma}(\tau) c^\dagger_{p\sigma}(0) c_{k\sigma}(0)] \rangle
\end{equation}
Moving to the case of Josephson tunnelling at p.653, Mahan is once again interested in a similar correlator:
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega) = -\sum_{kp\sigma} \sum_{k'p'\sigma'} T_{kp} T^*_{k'p'} \int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau} \langle \mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{k\sigma}(\tau)c_{p\sigma}(\tau) c^\dagger_{k'\sigma'}(0) c_{p'\sigma'}(0)] \rangle
\end{equation}
However this time only the $k=-k', p=-p', \sigma=-\sigma'$ case is considered so that
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega)=2\sum_{kp} T_{k,p} T_{-k,-p}\int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau} \langle \mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}(\tau) c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}(0) c_{-p\downarrow}(0)c_{p\uparrow}(\tau)]\rangle
\end{equation}
Since the two sides of the tunnelling junction are independent of each other, we can factor out the correlation functions for $k$ states and $p$ states to get
\begin{equation}
\Phi(i\omega)=2\sum_{kp} T_{k,p} T_{-k,-p}\int_0^\beta d\tau \ e^{i\omega \tau} \langle \mathcal{T}[c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}(\tau) c^\dagger_{-k\downarrow}(0)]\rangle \langle \mathcal{T}[c_{-p\downarrow}(0)c_{p\uparrow}(\tau)]\rangle
\end{equation}
Where does this momentum and spin selection come from?

Comment: Are the matrix elements $T_{kp}$ different in the first/second and third/fourth equations?

Comment: i do not think so since both equations pop up from the same tunnelling hamiltonian, they just represent different contributions to the current.

Comment: OK, I would have to read the passage in Mahan to understand. What edition of the textbook do the page numbers refer to?

Comment: Third edition, thanks for the help.

Comment: You seem to have mistyped and elided a lot of what is in Mahan. In the both cases, the Hamiltonian is for tunneling and the p and k are on different sides of the barrier and so the correlator separates into a product for the left and right sides of the junction. You need to include details like this or you will not receive a meaningful answer.

Comment: It's not clear to me how anyone could answer this question as written. It should be edited or closed.

Comment: Yes but the factoring of the correlator follows trivially, the selection of the momenta is what is not immediately trivial to me. Could you point me to where I have made typographic mistakes?

Comment: Follows trivially from what?

Comment: From the fact that the two sides of the tunnelling junction are independent of each other and don't interact.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't state that in your question. It's stated in the textbook as an assumption. You also don't state that p and k refer to different sides of the junction.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you are looking for someone to answer your question you might want to make it easy for them. Not everyone is going to know or assume this from context and almost no one is going to look up the section of Mahan you are referring to. The question should be as complete as possible without reference to the textbook...

Comment: Yes thank you for the advice. I'll fill in some details that i have omitted.

Answer (score 0):

This is tunneling of Cooper pairs, which are boson-like excitations with zero net momentum and zero net spin (zero momentum allows a very intuitive picture of superconductivity as Bose-Einstein condensation of Cooper pairs).

Comment: Yes, I understand physically that the Josephson effect arises from Cooper pair tunnelling, but I can't quite see how this arises from the equations. How do we know that only the Cooper pairs give correlations, why is $\langle c^\dagger_{k\sigma} c^\dagger_{k'\sigma'}\rangle$ non-vanishing only for $k=-k', \sigma=-\sigma'$ at finite temperature?

Comment: As I said, because total momentum and total spin of a Cooper pair is zero: $k+k'=0$, $\sigma+\sigma'=0$. They're of course other contributions, due to *quasiparticles*, but these are small, since they involve excitations above the superconductor gap. On the level of the discussion given in mahan they can be omitted - and this is a rather good approximation.

Comment: Aaah, I see. So we can ignore all other contributions due to excitations and consider only the current carried by cooper pairing.